# Is the following system memory or memoryless and linear or nonlinear?

Tags: signal-processing

Is this system memory or memoryless and linear or nonlinear? I can't understand whether it is memory or memoryless and linear or nonlinear when u[n] is involved. Please help me out.

y[n] = x[n]+3u[n+1]

TIA.

Comment: Could you elaborate what signals y, x, and u are? Maybe output, input and some auxiliary signal?

Comment: y[n] output signal, x[n] input signal and u[n] unit step signal. @Mouse On Mars

Comment: What have you tried, what are your thoughts why it would be memory(less) & (non)linear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear system since output is computed with linear combination (addition and scaling of two signals i.e. input and unit-step). This is not memoryless system since in order to compute output (y[n]) at time-instance **n** you need unit-step u[n+1] i.e. a time-point in future **n+1**